# Multiple access control on a web page - C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, social-networking

In my company we're currently working in our portal. It will be something like a social network.

I'm working on the "profile" part of the portal.

I was wondering, as I'm new to C#, how can I implement a "see-only-what-i-let-you" functionality.

Take for instance Facebook. There you can show only parts of your profile to some people, other parts to other people, you have full acess as others may have no acess at all.

That's precisely what I need to implement.

We're working with MVC3/jQuery1.5/WCF.

Comment: here i think answer is in your question itself as you know only friends ,public ,friends of friends.there must be a relation between member ids of all so if that is present you can use that one to show the recpord/part of profile.

Comment: This question isn't really related to C#, .net, MVC etc.  It's a question of general application/architecture design of your website.  The answer is heavily dependant on the architecture of the rest of the application.

Comment: @James I'm sorry but I disagree with you. Even though it does involve architectural/design issues, my main question is how to do that using C# tech. Thanks.

Comment: @AtInfo - fair enough - you're free to ask any questions you want of course.  My advice then would be if you're thinking in terms of C# tech at this stage - you're probably jumping in to the detail too early without thinking about the bigger picture.

Comment: @James Ok. As I said my problem is to work with the technology, mainly how can I control what each user can see on a page using C# tech. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem.  To answer that point specifically - if you're using MVC I would split the page up in to separate child actions.  Each child actions controller would check whether the user can see that particular piece of the page and if not it wouldn't render anything.  That's one option anyway.

Comment: @James thanks, but wouldn't that consume too much bandwidth? I mean, lots of users accessing that page would probably slow down the server, right? Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by bandwidth? It doesn't impact network access - as child actions are entirely rendered on the server - it's not like an iframe for example.  In terms of processing bandwidth - yes it would have an impact - but so would any solution.  Don't worry about processor optimisation until you've got a working solution - premature optimisation being the root of evil and all that.  In any case it's not a particularly processor intensive solution in itself. It depends how you implement it - mainly with regards database access downstream and whether you cache data across child actions.

Comment: Another way of looking at it - a lot of users accessing the page is always going to slow down the server.  There are only 2 solutions - have more servers or have less users.  The third option of trying to be super clever and cut corners in design/functionality usually leads to a bad site and ends you up at the less users solution in any case.

Comment: @James Ok, can you post that as answer and provide a simple snippet of what you mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to split your view up in to child actions:

```
@{Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layouts/MasterLayout.cshtml";}
<div class="splitter">
    <div class="left-column">
       @Html.Action("Navigator")
       @Html.Action("MyPosts")
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
       @Html.Action("RecentStories")
       @Html.Action("Adverts")
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your controller each action decides if the current user can see this piece of content, e.g.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult RecentStories()
{
    if(current_user_cannot_access_this_content())
        return View("BlankView"); // Might want to render some place holder content

    // Setup necessary view data by pulling back content from the database.....

    return View(); // Render the /Views/<controller>/RecentStories.cshtml view 
}
```

Try to cache user permission data across child actions if possible (depends on how your calculation of what a user can see works).

This code is assuming all your actions are running off the same controller.  You can hit a different controller for a child action just by passing the name of the controller as the second parameter.